# Integrating Google Health Connect into Xamarin Forms Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-health

We need to integrate our Xamarin Forms project with Google Health Connect.

I realise there is no out of the box support in XF and in the past I have creating binding libraries for unsupported AAR packages.

Where do i find the native library for Health Connect? Are there in exisiting xamarin integrations?

Answer (score 1):

Health Connect library is still [alpha](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/health-connect#version_10_2), and Xamarin [does not](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6517#issuecomment-985650094) bind non-stable packages, so you need to do it manually and wait for official release.

You can also create an issue on [Xamarin.Android GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android).